# Massive Python random sharer

Tags: python, python-2.7, random

I tried to make a program to take a certain amount of elements and randomly generate them. For example, the user could enter twenty names and have the algorithm spit them out randomly. I built the program in such a way that you could enter up to twenty elements, and it would print out that number plus one random things. So you could enter twenty elements and it would randomly choose from them twenty-one times. The problem is I'm not all too experience with random, so I made it ridiculously large (just shy of 500 lines). It works, but I'd like:
1) For it to be shortened. 2) To take any number, rather than between 2 and 20 and 3) To be able to spit out a user-entered number of random items. I don't know if any of that made sense, but help if you can!
The whole massive code:

```
import random
a = input('Enter a number of elements(maximum twenty).\n')
if a < 2 or a > 20:
    print('Restart program and enter a value between two and twenty.')
if(a == 2):
    one = raw_input('Enter the first element.\n')
    two = raw_input('Enter the second element.\n')
    list_one = [one,two]
    choice_one = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_two = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_three = random.choice(list_one)
    print(choice_one, choice_two, choice_three)
if(a == 3):
    one = raw_input('Enter the first element.\n')
    two = raw_input('Enter the second element.\n')
    three = raw_input('Enter the third element.\n')
    list_one = [one,two,three]
    choice_one = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_two = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_three = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_four = random.choice(list_one)
    print(choice_one, choice_two, choice_three, choice_four)
if(a == 4):
    one = raw_input('Enter the first element.\n')
    two = raw_input('Enter the second element.\n')
    three = raw_input('Enter the third element.\n')
    four = raw_input('Enter the fourth element.\n')
    list_one = [one,two,three,four]
    choice_one = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_two = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_three = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_four = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_five = random.choice(list_one)
    print(choice_one, choice_two, choice_three, choice_four, choice_five)
if(a == 5):
    one = raw_input('Enter the first element.\n')
    two = raw_input('Enter the second element.\n')
    three = raw_input('Enter the third element.\n')
    four = raw_input('Enter the fourth element.\n')
    five = raw_input('Enter the fifth element.\n')
    list_one = [one,two,three,four,five]
    choice_one = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_two = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_three = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_four = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_five = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_six = random.choice(list_one)
    print(choice_one, choice_two, choice_three, choice_four, choice_five, choice_six)
if(a == 6):
    one = raw_input('Enter the first element.\n')
    two = raw_input('Enter the second element.\n')
    three = raw_input('Enter the third element.\n')
    four = raw_input('Enter the fourth element.\n')
    five = raw_input('Enter the fifth element.\n')
    six = raw_input('Enter the sixth element.\n')
    list_one = [one,two,three,four,five,six]
    choice_one = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_two = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_three = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_four = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_five = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_six = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_seven = random.choice(list_one)
    print(choice_one, choice_two, choice_three, choice_four, choice_five, choice_six, choice_seven)
if(a == 7):
    one = raw_input('Enter the first element.\n')
    two = raw_input('Enter the second element.\n')
    three = raw_input('Enter the third element.\n')
    four = raw_input('Enter the fourth element.\n')
    five = raw_input('Enter the fifth element.\n')
    six = raw_input('Enter the sixth element.\n')
    seven = raw_input('Enter the seventh element.\n')
    list_one = [one,two,three,four,five,six,seven]
    choice_one = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_two = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_three = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_four = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_five = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_six = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_seven = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_eight = random.choice(list_one)
    print(choice_one, choice_two, choice_three, choice_four, choice_five, choice_six, choice_seven, choice_eight)
if(a == 8):
    one = raw_input('Enter the first element.\n')
    two = raw_input('Enter the second element.\n')
    three = raw_input('Enter the third element.\n')
    four = raw_input('Enter the fourth element.\n')
    five = raw_input('Enter the fifth element.\n')
    six = raw_input('Enter the sixth element.\n')
    seven = raw_input('Enter the seventh element.\n')
    eight = raw_input('Enter the eighth element.\n')
    list_one = [one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,]
    choice_one = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_two = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_three = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_four = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_five = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_six = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_seven = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_eight = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_nine = random.choice(list_one)
    print(choice_one, choice_two, choice_three, choice_four, choice_five, choice_six, choice_seven, choice_eight, choice_nine)
if(a == 9):
    one = raw_input('Enter the first element.\n')
    two = raw_input('Enter the second element.\n')
    three = raw_input('Enter the third element.\n')
    four = raw_input('Enter the fourth element.\n')
    five = raw_input('Enter the fifth element.\n')
    six = raw_input('Enter the sixth element.\n')
    seven = raw_input('Enter the seventh element.\n')
    eight = raw_input('Enter the eighth element.\n')
    nine = raw_input('Enter the ninth element.\n')
    list_one = [one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine]
    choice_one = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_two = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_three = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_four = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_five = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_six = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_seven = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_eight = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_nine = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_ten = random.choice(list_one)
    print(choice_one, choice_two, choice_three, choice_four, choice_five, choice_six, choice_seven, choice_eight, choice_nine, choice_ten)
if(a == 10):
    one = raw_input('Enter the first element.\n')
    two = raw_input('Enter the second element.\n')
    three = raw_input('Enter the third element.\n')
    four = raw_input('Enter the fourth element.\n')
    five = raw_input('Enter the fifth element.\n')
    six = raw_input('Enter the sixth element.\n')
    seven = raw_input('Enter the seventh element.\n')
    eight = raw_input('Enter the eighth element.\n')
    nine = raw_input('Enter the ninth element.\n')
    ten = raw_input('Enter the tenth element.\n')
    list_one = [one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten]
    choice_one = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_two = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_three = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_four = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_five = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_six = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_seven = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_eight = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_nine = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_ten = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_eleven = random.choice(list_one)
    print(choice_one, choice_two, choice_three, choice_four, choice_five, choice_six, choice_seven, choice_eight, choice_nine, choice_ten, choice_eleven)
if(a == 11):
    one = raw_input('Enter the first element.\n')
    two = raw_input('Enter the second element.\n')
    three = raw_input('Enter the third element.\n')
    four = raw_input('Enter the fourth element.\n')
    five = raw_input('Enter the fifth element.\n')
    six = raw_input('Enter the sixth element.\n')
    seven = raw_input('Enter the seventh element.\n')
    eight = raw_input('Enter the eighth element.\n')
    nine = raw_input('Enter the ninth element.\n')
    ten = raw_input('Enter the tenth element.\n')
    eleven = raw_input('Enter the eleventh element.\n')
    list_one = [one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten,eleven]
    choice_one = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_two = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_three = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_four = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_five = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_six = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_seven = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_eight = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_nine = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_ten = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_eleven = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_twelve = random.choice(list_one)
    print(choice_one, choice_two, choice_three, choice_four, choice_five, choice_six, choice_seven, choice_eight, choice_nine, choice_ten, choice_eleven, choice_twelve)
if(a == 12):
    one = raw_input('Enter the first element.\n')
    two = raw_input('Enter the second element.\n')
    three = raw_input('Enter the third element.\n')
    four = raw_input('Enter the fourth element.\n')
    five = raw_input('Enter the fifth element.\n')
    six = raw_input('Enter the sixth element.\n')
    seven = raw_input('Enter the seventh element.\n')
    eight = raw_input('Enter the eighth element.\n')
    nine = raw_input('Enter the ninth element.\n')
    ten = raw_input('Enter the tenth element.\n')
    eleven = raw_input('Enter the eleventh element.\n')
    twelve = raw_input('Enter the twelth element.\n')
    list_one = [one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten,eleven,twelve]
    choice_one = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_two = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_three = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_four = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_five = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_six = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_seven = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_eight = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_nine = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_ten = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_eleven = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_twelve = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_thirteen = random.choice(list_one)
    print(choice_one, choice_two, choice_three, choice_four, choice_five, choice_six, choice_seven, choice_eight, choice_nine, choice_ten, choice_eleven, choice_twelve, choice_thirteen)
if(a == 13):
    one = raw_input('Enter the first element.\n')
    two = raw_input('Enter the second element.\n')
    three = raw_input('Enter the third element.\n')
    four = raw_input('Enter the fourth element.\n')
    five = raw_input('Enter the fifth element.\n')
    six = raw_input('Enter the sixth element.\n')
    seven = raw_input('Enter the seventh element.\n')
    eight = raw_input('Enter the eighth element.\n')
    nine = raw_input('Enter the ninth element.\n')
    ten = raw_input('Enter the tenth element.\n')
    eleven = raw_input('Enter the eleventh element.\n')
    twelve = raw_input('Enter the twelth element.\n')
    thirteen = raw_input('Enter the thirteenth element.\n')
    list_one = [one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten,eleven,twelve,thirteen]
    choice_one = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_two = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_three = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_four = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_five = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_six = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_seven = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_eight = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_nine = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_ten = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_eleven = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_twelve = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_thirteen = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_fourteen = random.choice(list_one)
    print(choice_one, choice_two, choice_three, choice_four, choice_five, choice_six, choice_seven, choice_eight, choice_nine, choice_ten, choice_eleven, choice_twelve, choice_thirteen, choice_fourteen)
if(a == 14):
    one = raw_input('Enter the first element.\n')
    two = raw_input('Enter the second element.\n')
    three = raw_input('Enter the third element.\n')
    four = raw_input('Enter the fourth element.\n')
    five = raw_input('Enter the fifth element.\n')
    six = raw_input('Enter the sixth element.\n')
    seven = raw_input('Enter the seventh element.\n')
    eight = raw_input('Enter the eighth element.\n')
    nine = raw_input('Enter the ninth element.\n')
    ten = raw_input('Enter the tenth element.\n')
    eleven = raw_input('Enter the eleventh element.\n')
    twelve = raw_input('Enter the twelth element.\n')
    thirteen = raw_input('Enter the thirteenth element.\n')
    fourteen = raw_input('Enter the fourteenth element.\n')
    list_one = [one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten,eleven,twelve,thirteen,fourteen]
    choice_one = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_two = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_three = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_four = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_five = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_six = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_seven = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_eight = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_nine = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_ten = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_eleven = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_twelve = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_thirteen = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_fourteen = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_fifteen = random.choice(list_one)
    print(choice_one, choice_two, choice_three, choice_four, choice_five, choice_six, choice_seven, choice_eight, choice_nine, choice_ten, choice_eleven, choice_twelve, choice_thirteen, choice_fourteen, choice_fifteen)
if(a == 15):
    one = raw_input('Enter the first element.\n')
    two = raw_input('Enter the second element.\n')
    three = raw_input('Enter the third element.\n')
    four = raw_input('Enter the fourth element.\n')
    five = raw_input('Enter the fifth element.\n')
    six = raw_input('Enter the sixth element.\n')
    seven = raw_input('Enter the seventh element.\n')
    eight = raw_input('Enter the eighth element.\n')
    nine = raw_input('Enter the ninth element.\n')
    ten = raw_input('Enter the tenth element.\n')
    eleven = raw_input('Enter the eleventh element.\n')
    twelve = raw_input('Enter the twelth element.\n')
    thirteen = raw_input('Enter the thirteenth element.\n')
    fourteen = raw_input('Enter the fourteenth element.\n')
    fifteen = raw_input('Enter the fifteenth element.\n')
    list_one = [one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten,eleven,twelve,thirteen,fourteen,fifteen]
    choice_one = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_two = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_three = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_four = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_five = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_six = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_seven = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_eight = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_nine = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_ten = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_eleven = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_twelve = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_thirteen = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_fourteen = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_fifteen = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_sixteen = random.choice(list_one)
    print(choice_one, choice_two, choice_three, choice_four, choice_five, choice_six, choice_seven, choice_eight, choice_nine, choice_ten, choice_eleven, choice_twelve, choice_thirteen, choice_fourteen, choice_fifteen,choice_sixteen)
if(a == 16):
    one = raw_input('Enter the first element.\n')
    two = raw_input('Enter the second element.\n')
    three = raw_input('Enter the third element.\n')
    four = raw_input('Enter the fourth element.\n')
    five = raw_input('Enter the fifth element.\n')
    six = raw_input('Enter the sixth element.\n')
    seven = raw_input('Enter the seventh element.\n')
    eight = raw_input('Enter the eighth element.\n')
    nine = raw_input('Enter the ninth element.\n')
    ten = raw_input('Enter the tenth element.\n')
    eleven = raw_input('Enter the eleventh element.\n')
    twelve = raw_input('Enter the twelth element.\n')
    thirteen = raw_input('Enter the thirteenth element.\n')
    fourteen = raw_input('Enter the fourteenth element.\n')
    fifteen = raw_input('Enter the fifteenth element.\n')
    sixteen = raw_input('Enter the sixteenth element.\n')
    list_one = [one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten,eleven,twelve,thirteen,fourteen,fifteen,sixteen]
    choice_one = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_two = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_three = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_four = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_five = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_six = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_seven = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_eight = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_nine = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_ten = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_eleven = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_twelve = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_thirteen = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_fourteen = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_fifteen = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_sixteen = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_seventeen = random.choice(list_one)
    print(choice_one, choice_two, choice_three, choice_four, choice_five, choice_six, choice_seven, choice_eight, choice_nine, choice_ten, choice_eleven, choice_twelve, choice_thirteen, choice_fourteen, choice_fifteen,choice_sixteen, choice_seventeen)
if(a == 17):
    one = raw_input('Enter the first element.\n')
    two = raw_input('Enter the second element.\n')
    three = raw_input('Enter the third element.\n')
    four = raw_input('Enter the fourth element.\n')
    five = raw_input('Enter the fifth element.\n')
    six = raw_input('Enter the sixth element.\n')
    seven = raw_input('Enter the seventh element.\n')
    eight = raw_input('Enter the eighth element.\n')
    nine = raw_input('Enter the ninth element.\n')
    ten = raw_input('Enter the tenth element.\n')
    eleven = raw_input('Enter the eleventh element.\n')
    twelve = raw_input('Enter the twelth element.\n')
    thirteen = raw_input('Enter the thirteenth element.\n')
    fourteen = raw_input('Enter the fourteenth element.\n')
    fifteen = raw_input('Enter the fifteenth element.\n')
    sixteen = raw_input('Enter the sixteenth element.\n')
    seventeen = raw_input('Enter the seventeenth element.\n')
    list_one = [one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten,eleven,twelve,thirteen,fourteen,fifteen,sixteen,seventeen]
    choice_one = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_two = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_three = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_four = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_five = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_six = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_seven = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_eight = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_nine = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_ten = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_eleven = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_twelve = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_thirteen = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_fourteen = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_fifteen = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_sixteen = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_seventeen = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_eighteen = random.choice(list_one)
    print(choice_one, choice_two, choice_three, choice_four, choice_five, choice_six, choice_seven, choice_eight, choice_nine, choice_ten, choice_eleven, choice_twelve, choice_thirteen, choice_fourteen, choice_fifteen,choice_sixteen, choice_seventeen, choice_eighteen)
if(a == 18):
    one = raw_input('Enter the first element.\n')
    two = raw_input('Enter the second element.\n')
    three = raw_input('Enter the third element.\n')
    four = raw_input('Enter the fourth element.\n')
    five = raw_input('Enter the fifth element.\n')
    six = raw_input('Enter the sixth element.\n')
    seven = raw_input('Enter the seventh element.\n')
    eight = raw_input('Enter the eighth element.\n')
    nine = raw_input('Enter the ninth element.\n')
    ten = raw_input('Enter the tenth element.\n')
    eleven = raw_input('Enter the eleventh element.\n')
    twelve = raw_input('Enter the twelth element.\n')
    thirteen = raw_input('Enter the thirteenth element.\n')
    fourteen = raw_input('Enter the fourteenth element.\n')
    fifteen = raw_input('Enter the fifteenth element.\n')
    sixteen = raw_input('Enter the sixteenth element.\n')
    seventeen = raw_input('Enter the seventeenth element.\n')
    eighteen = raw_input('Enter the eighteenth element.\n')
    list_one = [one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten,eleven,twelve,thirteen,fourteen,fifteen,sixteen,seventeen,eighteen]
    choice_one = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_two = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_three = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_four = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_five = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_six = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_seven = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_eight = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_nine = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_ten = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_eleven = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_twelve = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_thirteen = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_fourteen = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_fifteen = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_sixteen = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_seventeen = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_eighteen = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_nineteen = random.choice(list_one)
    print(choice_one, choice_two, choice_three, choice_four, choice_five, choice_six, choice_seven, choice_eight, choice_nine, choice_ten, choice_eleven, choice_twelve, choice_thirteen, choice_fourteen, choice_fifteen,choice_sixteen, choice_seventeen, choice_eighteen, choice_nineteen)
if(a == 19):
    one = raw_input('Enter the first element.\n')
    two = raw_input('Enter the second element.\n')
    three = raw_input('Enter the third element.\n')
    four = raw_input('Enter the fourth element.\n')
    five = raw_input('Enter the fifth element.\n')
    six = raw_input('Enter the sixth element.\n')
    seven = raw_input('Enter the seventh element.\n')
    eight = raw_input('Enter the eighth element.\n')
    nine = raw_input('Enter the ninth element.\n')
    ten = raw_input('Enter the tenth element.\n')
    eleven = raw_input('Enter the eleventh element.\n')
    twelve = raw_input('Enter the twelth element.\n')
    thirteen = raw_input('Enter the thirteenth element.\n')
    fourteen = raw_input('Enter the fourteenth element.\n')
    fifteen = raw_input('Enter the fifteenth element.\n')
    sixteen = raw_input('Enter the sixteenth element.\n')
    seventeen = raw_input('Enter the seventeenth element.\n')
    eighteen = raw_input('Enter the eighteenth element.\n')
    nineteen = raw_input('Enter the ninteenth element.\n')
    list_one = [one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten,eleven,twelve,thirteen,fourteen,fifteen,sixteen,seventeen,eighteen,nineteen]
    choice_one = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_two = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_three = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_four = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_five = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_six = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_seven = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_eight = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_nine = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_ten = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_eleven = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_twelve = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_thirteen = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_fourteen = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_fifteen = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_sixteen = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_seventeen = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_eighteen = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_nineteen = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_twenty = random.choice(list_one)
    print(choice_one, choice_two, choice_three, choice_four, choice_five, choice_six, choice_seven, choice_eight, choice_nine, choice_ten, choice_eleven, choice_twelve, choice_thirteen, choice_fourteen, choice_fifteen,choice_sixteen, choice_seventeen, choice_eighteen, choice_nineteen, choice_twenty)
if(a == 20):
    one = raw_input('Enter the first element.\n')
    two = raw_input('Enter the second element.\n')
    three = raw_input('Enter the third element.\n')
    four = raw_input('Enter the fourth element.\n')
    five = raw_input('Enter the fifth element.\n')
    six = raw_input('Enter the sixth element.\n')
    seven = raw_input('Enter the seventh element.\n')
    eight = raw_input('Enter the eighth element.\n')
    nine = raw_input('Enter the ninth element.\n')
    ten = raw_input('Enter the tenth element.\n')
    eleven = raw_input('Enter the eleventh element.\n')
    twelve = raw_input('Enter the twelth element.\n')
    thirteen = raw_input('Enter the thirteenth element.\n')
    fourteen = raw_input('Enter the fourteenth element.\n')
    fifteen = raw_input('Enter the fifteenth element.\n')
    sixteen = raw_input('Enter the sixteenth element.\n')
    seventeen = raw_input('Enter the seventeenth element.\n')
    eighteen = raw_input('Enter the eighteenth element.\n')
    nineteen = raw_input('Enter the ninteenth element.\n')
    twenty = raw_input('Enter the twentieth element.\n')
    list_one = [one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten,eleven,twelve,thirteen,fourteen,fifteen,sixteen,seventeen,eighteen,nineteen,twenty]
    choice_one = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_two = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_three = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_four = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_five = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_six = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_seven = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_eight = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_nine = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_ten = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_eleven = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_twelve = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_thirteen = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_fourteen = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_fifteen = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_sixteen = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_seventeen = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_eighteen = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_nineteen = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_twenty = random.choice(list_one)
    choice_twenty_one = random.choice(list_one)
    print(choice_one, choice_two, choice_three, choice_four, choice_five, choice_six, choice_seven, choice_eight, choice_nine, choice_ten, choice_eleven, choice_twelve, choice_thirteen, choice_fourteen, choice_fifteen,choice_sixteen, choice_seventeen, choice_eighteen, choice_nineteen, choice_twenty, choice_twenty_one)
raw_input('Press enter to exit.')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes! There is a simple way. If you notice, for a number, `n`, you make `n` actions, so that can be simplified to a loop.

```
import random

n = int(raw_input('Number: '))
items = raw_input('Items: ').split()

choices = [random.choice(items) for _ in xrange(n)]
print choices
```

I've made it so you can input all the items in one go with a space as a delimeter, but that's something you can change. When you run it, you get

```
Number: 5
Items: '1 4 6 56 45 34 7 12 fgtr hyt 98 0 98 78 6666666666.6'
['56', '98', "6666666666.6'", '7', 'fgtr']
```

Now, as you will see in many questions, trusting the input the user will give you is not a wise idea, so wrap the input for a number in a try statement and repeat it as many times as necessary until you get an integer.

```
while True:
    try:
        n = int(raw_input('Number: '))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print 'Gimme an integer please!'
```

Another thing, if you want your list to have as many items as the number, you can use another loop for that.

```
items = [raw_input('Input item number {}'.format(i+1)) for i in xrange(n)]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it doesn't require 499 lines just to do something that only takes five.

Comment: @Mathime In case you didn't see it, I edited the answer to show how you can ask the user to input `n` number of items only. As a general rule of thumb, if you're repeating a lot of actions, there is probably a way of using a loop. And if you're replicating the same code in many places, you can probably put that in a function and call it in one line.

Answer (score 0):

for example

```
import random
a = input('Enter a number of elements(maximum twenty).\n')

if a < 2 and a > 20:
   elements = []
   elementsramdon = []
   for x in range(a):
       uservalue = raw_input('Enter the element.\n')
       elements.append(uservalue) # this line contain the real values
       elementsramdom.append(random.choice(uservalue)) # ramdon values
```

now for print ramdom values

```
for x in elementsramdom:
    print x
```

or if you want by comma separate [x,y,z]

```
print ([x for x in elementsrandom])
```